# Which one is the correct way to use h1 tag?

Tags: seo, html, technical-seo, h1

In a website that provides content which is divided into parts, what is the more correct way to use the `H1` tag?

```html
<div class='header'>
  <span>Episode 2</span>
  <h1 class='large'>Creative work name</h1>
</div>
<!-- content body -->
```

or:

```html
<div class='header'>
  <h1>Episode 2</h1>
  <span class='large'>Creative work name</span>
</div>
<!-- content body -->
```

Comment: What is the title of your page? Is this a page for a single episode, or a page that lists multiple episodes? Generally you want your `h1` to be similar to your page title.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister it's only for a single episode, the page title is "Creative work name episode 2"

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister +1 for pointing out the page title component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to run into duplicate `<h1>` tags across other episode pages if the `<h1>` only includes creative work name.

Speaking of semantics, why are we using `<div class="header">` when we have the `<header>` element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ep. 2, Creative Work Name - Example.com</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <span class="top-of-page-section">Episode 2</span>
    <div>
    <header>
        <h1>Creative Work Name - Ep 2</h1>
        <h2 class="subhead">The one about heading tags</h2>
    </header>

    <!-- Rest of page content + video, etc -->

    <footer></footer>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I added a couple other nuances as well.

*Edit:* Put the span in a div and added a header beneath. I kept the span to retain the format of your original example in your question, though it seems redundant to me (see below for what *I* would do. This should resolve the comments all of this without actually *seeing* the page is hard.

Personally, I'd probably do this and ditch the `<span>` if it's not necessary:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ep. 2, Creative Work Name - Example.com</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Creative Work Name - Ep 2</h1>
        <h2 class="subhead">The one about heading tags</h2>
    </header>

    <!-- Rest of page -->

    <footer></footer>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The body being the main section of your document, I don't believe the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags should be outside the main `<body>` tag semantically.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee 100% nice catch. I tabbed boilerplate html in vscode and was going fast ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: shouldn't `h1` be inside header tag?

Comment: `<h1>` and `<h2>` should _definetly_ go within the `<header>`.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma Not necessarily and there is no such requirement in the standard.

Comment: @Rob Although it isn't _required_, the standard does _suggest_ this, and semantically it makes the most sense --- especially given the alternative presented by this answer. Semantically, a `<header>` represents an introduction to the following content and potentially some navigation --- I'm sure you'd agree the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags as used in this answer are part of the introduction to the content, and thus they should be within the `<header>`.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma  I'm fairly certain that the `<span>` with the episode number is near the top left corner of the page a bit below the nav. Then there's probably the video itself, and then beneath which there is the `<h1>` with the name of the creative work followed by a few paragraphs of summary/description text. The semantics of the markup don't even really matter to the question tho. Google doesn't care, they're just looking for a unique `<h1>` to understand the content. This is splitting hairs at this point.

Comment: @Bouh I edited the answer to address your question. You can put the `<h1>` in the `<header>` if you want. The markup I provided is simply for the sake of example.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Creative work name` because,

It would be ridiculous for Google to crawl the website and see the title as `Episode 2`. The H1 title should be whatever that page is. The `Episode 2` here might be H2 but it would be ridiculous if it was H1.

So this is my answer:

```
<div class='header'>
 <span>Episode 2</span>
 <h1 class='large'>Creative work name</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The page should be constructed [semantically](https://html.com/semantic-markup/) with no consideration to layout or style at all. In my opinion the correct markup should be:

```
<div class='header'>
  <h1>Creative work name</h1>
  <span>Episode 2</span>
</div>
```

This makes the most sense to Google, and to screen-readers etc. Then simply use CSS to display the header however you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the episode number and name are equally important since the user may know one or the other. Generally, in HTML, the document body is the main section of your HTML page and can only contain a single H1. In HTML5 [the `<section>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#the-section-element) allows you to have multiple headers in the main document as long as they're within these section tags. If you plan on having numerous episodes on the same page you could use the following structure:

```
<body>
    <section id="episode1">
        <h1>Episode 1 <span style="display:block;">Creative work name</span></h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </section>
    
    <section id="episode2">
        <h1>Episode 2 <span style="display:block;">Creative work name</span></h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

The section IDs could also be used as [skip links for in-page navigation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/in-page-navigation/#skip-links). You should also add rich snippets within each section that will provide more context on the series, season, and episode. For more information, see the [TVEpisode Shema](https://schema.org/TVEpisode).

Comment: This could work for an "All Episodes" page, in fact, there are a _ton_ of ways to structure this, but OP stated in the comments that for the case in question, the page is only for a single episode. Nevertheless, I agree on using `episode` schema.